# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery, yii2

i wanted to add data to a table dynamically. i tried the following code

```
<?php

$script = <<<SKRIPT

$(document).on('submit', '#TaskCreateForm', function(event) {
  $.pjax.submit(event, '#PtlTasksPjax')
})

SKRIPT;

$this->registerJs($script);
$this->registerJs(
'
$("document").ready(function(){ 

    $("#receipt_details").click(function(e) {

        if ($("#receipt-date_of_payment").val() != "")
        {
            if ($("#receipt-payment_method_id").val() != "")
            {
                if ($("#receipt-name").val() != "")
                {
                    if($("#receipt-amount").val() != "")
                    {

                         $("#addfee tr").last().after("<tr><td><input type="text" name="Receipt[name][" + $("#receipt-name").val() + "][name]" value=" + $("#receipt-name").val() + " readonly="readonly"></td>" +
                    "<td><input type="text" name="Receipt[amount][" + $("#receipt-amount").val() + "][amount]" value=" + $("#receipt-amount").val() + " readonly="readonly"></td>" +
                    "<td><button>X</button></td></tr>");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Enter Amount");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Enter Receipt Name");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Enter Payment Method");
            e.preventDefault();
            }

        }
        else
        {
        alert("Enter Payment Date");
        e.preventDefault();
        }

        });
        });'
);
?>
```

i get a error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

this is the line where i get the syntax error

```
 $("#addfee tr").last().after("<tr><td><input type="text" name="Receipt[name][" + $("#receipt-name").val() + "][name]" value=" + $("#receipt-name").val() + " readonly="readonly"></td>" +
```

when i click on the button with id = "receipt_details" i want that data to be stored on the table

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="newtable">
                <table id="addfee" class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your string concatenation is having syntactical errors

Comment: okay could u help me rectify it

Comment: since you have `"` within the string literals you need to either escape it or use `''` to denote the string literal - `$("#addfee tr").last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="Receipt[name][" + $("#receipt-name").val() + "][name]" value=" + $("#receipt-name").val() + " readonly="readonly"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="Receipt[amount][" + $("#receipt-amount").val() + "][amount]" value=" + $("#receipt-amount").val() + " readonly="readonly"></td>' +
    '<td><button>X</button></td></tr>');`

Comment: i tried all i get is another error syntax error, unexpected '>'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p2mp153v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the string concatenation, since you are using `"` for the attribute values and for denoting string literals you need to escape those `"` within the literal or use `'` and `"` like

```
$("#addfee tr").last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="Receipt[name][' + $("#receipt-name").val() + '][name]" value="' + $("#receipt-name").val() + '" readonly="readonly"></td>' +
                            '<td><input type="text" name="Receipt[amount]["' + $("#receipt-amount").val() + '"][amount]" value="' + $("#receipt-amount").val() + '" readonly="readonly"></td>' +
                            '<td><button>X</button></td></tr>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p2mp153v/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape either change the `"` to `'` for the wrap of the string and escape and `"` with a `\` in the registerJs function which itself is uses `'` , most IDE's don't pick up the JS errors due to this